# Umbraco membership integration with SAML Web SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, umbraco, saml, saml-2.0

I have a requirement to integrate Umbraco membership with SAML Web SSO.

I have never integrated with it before and would like to have a bit of advise:

- Are there some existing modules for SAML WebSSO login in Umbraco?
- Could you recommend the approach/articles to start with?
- How hard could that be?

Thanks in advance, Anton.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're new to SAML 2.0, the wikipedia page is a worthwhile read to understand the main concepts of SAML.

A toolkit for Umbraco seems to exist: http://digitaliser.dk/resource/404629
This toolkit explains the integration with a specific SAML 2.0 Identity Provider, but as SAML 2.0 is norm, it should be compatible with any SAML 2.0-compliant IdP.

The other solution is to add the SAML 2.0 Service Provider manually in Umbraco. A good start point may be the Windows Identity Foundation SAML 2.0 toolkit released by Microsoft in May, that include code samples: http://connect.microsoft.com/site1168/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=36088